# I expect a single 'hello' as output but it showed 'hello' two times.Why?

Tags: python, decorator

```
def hello(hi):
    print('hello')

@hello
def hi():
    pass

hello(hi)
```

Output:

```
hello
hello
```

Comment: Because you're calling `hello` twice? Actually I'd expect a `NameError`; Python's case sensitive.

Comment: You are calling it twice, why do you expect it only once?

Comment: Look into decorators, you need another nested function inside `hello` to do what you think it should.

Comment: Can you explain in detail?

Comment: @dekalog If you just google the basics it'll explain a lot better than me - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator

Comment: What is the definition of `Print` function or did you mean built-in `print` ? Please clarify or fix the syntax.

Comment: @jonrsharpe FWIW it doesn't raise a `NameError` because the decorator doesn't have a return value.  The `hi()` function is never called so no `NameError`.

Comment: @Iguananaut but `Print('hello')` _is_ reached, even if `Pass` isn't.

Comment: @hc_dev I assume OP meant the built-in `print`, since the same error is there for "`Pass`".

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso please don't change the code people post, you risk obscuring the very thing they're asking about.

Comment: @jonrsharpe feel free to revert it then, but I think we can be pretty confident in this case that it was a typo.

Comment: Ah, true.  Who even knows then.

Answer (score 2):

We have two calls to `hello` here, marked below.

```
def hello(hi):
    print('hello')

@hello    # <-- 1st call
def hi():
    pass

hello(hi) # <-- 2nd call
```

The first one seems to be the one causing the confusion. The decorator (with the `@` symbol) is essentially doing this:

```
def hi():
    pass
hi = hello(hi)
```

When we look at what the decorator is doing, we can clearly see the first call to `hello`.

I should also point out that `hello` doesn't use its parameter at all, which probably isn't intended here.